# Instagram Subscription API - Subscription end points for comments

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Does anyone know of a way to subscribe to all activity (media posts, comments, likes etc) at a user level?  I am building an app to receive feeds from subscribed users, but that is working only for new media posts.  As per Instagram documentation, they say they only support "media" aspect for now and will support other aspects later on.  So, wondering if anyone has been able to get access to the other "aspects".

Also, if anyone knows of a way to get *all* comments of a subscribed user via the API, please let me know.

> User subscriptions In the previous example, we set up a subscription
> to receive updates whenever one of our client's authenticated users
> posts a media. Note that this subscription is for all of the client's
> authenticated users, not just a specific user.
>
> Other than the required client_id, client_secret, and callback_url
> parameters, the two parameters you need to include in order to
> subscribe to all photo updates from a user are:
>
> object: The object you'd like to subscribe to (in this case, "user")
>
> aspect: The aspect of the object you'd like to subscribe to (in this
> case, "media"). Note that we only support "media" at this time, but we
> might support other types of subscriptions in the future.

Thanks.